# Typescript: Auto inference of Enum type is unexpected as compared to explicit typing

Tags: typescript, enums, discriminated-union

Consider this example:

```
enum ItemType {
  One = 'One',
  Two = 'Two',
  Three = 'Three'
}

interface CommonProps {
  cProp1?: string,
  cProp2?: number;
}

interface OneProps extends CommonProps {
  type: ItemType.One,
  prop1: string;
}

interface TwoProps extends CommonProps {
  type: ItemType.Two;
  prop2: number;
}

interface ThreeProps extends CommonProps {
  type: ItemType.Three,
  prop3: string;
}

type ItemProps = OneProps | TwoProps | ThreeProps;
```

The above code defines an enum for ItemType and then also defines what each type of item object expects as properties

If I now try to define some objects like this:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

// This does not work, see errors when creating an array
const obj1  = {
  type: ItemType.One,
  prop1: 'some value',
}

const obj2 = {
  type: ItemType.Two,
  prop2: 12
}

const obj3 = {
  type: ItemType.Three,
  prop3: 'some value'
}

const arr: Array<ItemProps> = [ obj1, obj2, obj3 ];
```

If you hover over obj1 in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAkgLsCAVAngB2FA3gKClAeREwF4oByI4cgGjyiQHcB7KM8p52%20pACwCdgpCn0HUcAXxw4AliAT8AZgEMAxpgDCzCBGYgACv2ZoAztnqrDxgIwB%20AFxQTcfnIDmdfJaNoATA6hwCAAjYH4AbklpOQUVdUJiK1MoYAAPBBAAEzMtHT0ks1x8OHRgR3hEVAwAOipPKDQfa0dnVxA3SKlZeTC4zE4ClPTQbKhc3QMfQvoSjHKEZFLqzkj8RuNfRyDQiKju2LV%20gSFBtIzR8fyp82LS%20cql0SF69bQAZhaXd07pWcwKiCDMhUQYAHwYLDBDGOwAKkWkAHoEQBaVFo9EYzFY7E43F49GIhHQmRmTLMYBmEDMOBQFj8ADWNCcQhS-CM-DMjF4oCgqkEyjg7igyhAwrZyhQOFUemcUGYwQAVtZ8GQilA-vdFjU6vRXs0KCZtJgAG7KAA2YGodC60pAsvlCt8bBu6rusAWVWAyxYLx8myg1l8e1t9sVb2dao17oeNSewF9xg%20BqNUFNFvENplNOUbMcAEFxSgADwAgoAPmdAG05YrrEyHb562GoABdSJI-GdrvdnvIwm9geDnuE4mc5gMszKMxpDCqBCZKVZmsKgAsjhB1wjMzdAM9tWICbQ%20vIhogJvNlu4mbtNIdAFZHANrqrt3No1qvZxD-7A8Glw6ADZHxhIEXSjXdHhhQ8kxPFM00vP8bzFfh-QLfgJRLBZyyrZcVybBU73wgDW3bFEh3IiisSAA)

you would see that obj1.type is typed as ItemType (and not the specific type ItemType.One), which is why when trying to create an Array ts complains.

However, when I explicitly add types to this:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

// This works as expected
const obj4: OneProps  = {
  type: ItemType.One,
  prop1: 'some value',
}

const obj5: TwoProps = {
  type: ItemType.Two,
  prop2: 12
}

const obj6: ThreeProps = {
  type: ItemType.Three,
  prop3: 'some value'
}

const arr2: Array<ItemProps> = [ obj4, obj5, obj6 ];
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

TS does not complain.

I guess this is something related to typescript widening the types by default when inferring, but some pointers for a better explanation would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

this is because

```js
const obj1  = {
  type: ItemType.One,
  prop1: 'some value',
}
```

is infered as

```js
{
    type: ItemType;
    prop1: string;
}
```

And above type is not assignable to `ItemProps`. In order to make it work, you can also use `satisfies` operator:

```js
const obj1  = {
  type: ItemType.One,
  prop1: 'some value',
} satisfies ItemProps

const arr: Array<ItemProps> = [ obj1]; // ok
```

or you can use `as const` assertion:

```js
const obj1  = {
  type: ItemType.One,
  prop1: 'some value',
} as const

const arr: Array<ItemProps> = [ obj1]; // ok
```

OR, you can use literals:

```js
const arr: Array<ItemProps> = [{
  type: ItemType.One,
  prop1: 'some value',
}]; // ok
```

It is just how type inference works in TypeScript